# API in nodejs Port Issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, error-handling, port

I've created an API in nodejs backend and frontend I used reactjs as I've connected the api to my form

it shows the error

> "Could Not proxy request"

[image]

Comment: Are you using `mozaik`? If yes, try https://github.com/plouc/mozaik/issues/118 Make sure you are in the correct folder when you run `npm start`

Comment: I'm using vscode and running on localhost:3000 and it displays the datatable too but can't able to load data in that due to this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what is the error in Chrome developer tools.  It is most probably CORS issue.

If you are using NodeJs, you can use below command.

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

But this will allow CORS for all port running on your machine.

I faced the same issue when using express. I resolved it as shown below :
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS OUT IN YOUR PACKAGE.JSON CONFIGURATION [refereed from create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3823#issuecomment-373194515)

```
"proxy": {
"/api": {
  "target": "https://localhost:5002",
  "secure": false
  }
},
```

Also try add CORS configuration to your node [check this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zoSJ3bNGPp0)